# Change host according to device project is running on

Tags: node.js, reactjs, localhost, ip-address

I was able to run my react-app locally as well as on mobile deivce over same wifi with the ip address. But the backend part of it didn't show untill I manually changed the code from :

```
app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Running on port 3001");
});
```

To:

```
var host = "192.168.xx.xx";
app.listen(3001, host, () => {
  console.log("Running on port 3001");
});
```

Then I realized I also need to change the code from my front-end, everywhere I try to use an API as:

```
Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/login", data).then((res) => {
  // code
})
```

To:

```
Axios.post("http://192.168.xx.xx:3001/login", data).then((res) => {
  // code
})
```

Isn't there an option to change host accrodingly when I use it on a IPaddress or locally as:

```
var hostValue;
if(host === local){
  hostValue = "localhost";
} else {
  hostValue = "192.168.xx.xx";
}
```

Expecting code for both Front-end(Login.js) and Back-end(index.js)